# Converse of Linearity of Power of a Point

Tags: geometry, power-of-the-point

The power of a point $P$ wrt a circle $\omega$ is given by $\mathbb{P}(P, \omega) = PO^2 - r^2$ where $O$ and $r$ are the center and radius of $\omega$ respectively. The statement of linearity of power of a point is as follows:

If $\mathbb{P}(P, \omega_1, \omega_2) = \mathbb{P}(P, \omega_1) - \mathbb{P}(P, \omega_2)$ and $F : \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ so that $F := \mathbb{P}(P, \omega_1, \omega_2)$ then $F$ is linear.

My question is regarding whether or not the "converse" of this statement is true; that is, whether or not points satisfying the relation $F(C) = \frac{F(A) \cdot {CB} + F(B) \cdot {CA}}{{AB}}$ implies that the points $A, B, C$ in question are collinear.

Comment: Your $F$ is called an "affine" function, technically. Important distinction. Of course, if the two circles' centers are antipodal WRT the origin, then $F$ is actually constant. Your question seems like it could be phrased for any nonconstant affine function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, without reference to power of a point. You should explain what your relation has to do with points being collinear. (And can you check its denominator is correct?)

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to ignore the notation altogether. The statement is essentially that the difference in power between two circles is a linear function, allowing you to take weighted averages similar in spirit to mass points, hence the fraction. The relation to being collinear is that the proof relies on Stewart’s theorem which in turn relies on A, B, C collinear. My question is whether the relation (fraction I gave above) can hold for non-collinear points A, B, C.

Comment: If you change the denominator to $AB$, the relation seems like a weighted average. But it doesn't seem to take into account signs, and I don't see how to account for signs in a way that doesn't assume $A,B,C$ are collinear...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The denominator should be AB. I will correct this. 

My idea was to reverse the steps of the derivation, but this hinges on the converse of Stewart's theorem being true which I am unsure of.

Answer (score 0):

No, the converse is not true. The affine space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas the output of $F$ must be in $\mathbb{R}$. So, just because the output of $F(C)$ is a linear combination of $F(A)$ and $F(B)$ does not mean it must lie on the line. It is impossible for that to be true, since that would mean every value in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would have to have a unique value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Or another way of viewing it is to consider the barycentric definition of linearity of power of a point, where point $X$ with barycentric coordinates $X = (p,q,r)$ with respect to triangle $\triangle ABC$ satisfies $F(X) = pF(A) + qF(B) + rF(C)$. From this it’s clear that there are infinitely many points with some value of $F$, and most of them will not line on the line that you want.